# Using potassium thiosulfate instead of sodium thiosulfate in iodine clock reaction

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I am familiar with the iodine clock reaction that uses sodium thiosulphate. Still, I'm wondering if I could use potassium thiosulphate instead, as it's the thiosulfate that reduces the Iodine.

Comment: I would not expect it to have a significant effect in your results. Check availabiltiy and price.

Comment: If you make corrections for different molar mass and ev. difference in crystal water, it should not matter.